# invert system of two parametric ODEs and plot results of do-loop

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions, inverse, iterators

I can solve this system of parametric ODE (`u` is the parameter,while `g`,`e` and `zi` are constants depends on the physic of the problem)

```
zf = -1/2;
g = 1;
e = .2;
Y[t_] :=  g/(2 zf) y[t] + u z[t];
Z[t_] := -g + g/zf z[t] - u y[t];
sol = 
  FullSimplify[
    DSolve[{y'[t] == Y[t], z'[t] == Z[t],y[0] == 0 , z[0] == -zf},
      {y[t], z[t]}, t]]
```

Then, I make the assignement:

```
zsol[t_] := Evaluate[z[t] /. sol[[1]][[2]]]
ysol[t_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. sol[[1]][[1]]]
```

My problem is to compare the time `t(u)` taken by trajectories `{y[t,u],z[t,u]}` to reach a neighborhood of `zf` whit radius `e`, with the time `trelax`, relative to `u=0` (`zf` is the fixed point of free dynamic). Not for all `u` the problem has solution: in general, for `u` large enough, trajectories reaches some fixed point in an infinity time following a spiral (as I seen plotting the system for various `u`), cause of the exponential-complex solutions, and there's a set of `u` without solutions (i.e, a set of `u` for which trajectories pass no close to `zf`). Then I have thought to use an iterative costruct, a `do-loop` mixed with an `If`. For simplicity, I've started, in particular, with:

```
trelax = Log[(-e/(2 zf))]*zf/g;
Do[Do[
   If[N[Abs[zsol[T]] <= (zf + e) && N[Abs[ysol[T]] <= e,
     If[NSolve[ysol[t], t] <= trelax], 
       Print[{T, u}]]], {T, 0, .9, .01}], {u, 0, 40, .2}]
```

Remark_1: `trelax` is the correct analytic result of dynamical system for `u=0`.
Remark_2: I expect from this code to obtain a list of couple `{t,u}`, with `t<=trelax` and `u>0`, but really I don't obtain nothing! I think I'm wrong in the definition of the variable in the function...and in many other things!

Finally I ask you if is it possible to change the loop to obtain directly a plot `{t,u}`, i.e. a curve to compare with constant `trelax`...

Thank you

P.S: If you want to see some plots, I attach the ad hoc code:

```
Clear[u]
u = 5;
ParametricPlot[{y[t] /. sol[[1]][[1]], z[t] /. sol[[1]][[2]]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange-> All]
```

Comment: Your `Do` loops as written have several missing brackets and incorrect capitalisation (Nsolve instead of NSolve).  What's the numerical value for `zf`?  `NSolve` gives a rule as a result, not a value which you can directly compare.  Maybe you want `Sow` and `Reap` rather than `Print`.

Comment: ok, thanks! actually I have written `zi` instead `zf` in the initial definitions. In my code (on my pc...) `NSolve` is written correctly, but don't work. Now I try to learn all about `Reap` and `Sow`...But, if you have understand my problem, do you think that my idea is right? What do I use instead NSolve?

Answer (score 1):

This was (partially answered on the mathematica-community site).

Here is that posting:

Without solving the problem of finding the condition where the trajectory lies within a disk.  This modification of your code may help you construct a numerical technique.

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[t] == g/(2 zf) y[t] + u z[t], 
               z'[t] == -g + g/zf z[t] - u y[t], y[0] == 0, z[0] == -zf},
             {y[t], z[t]}, t]
```

This is your original equation, but without putting in the defintions for Z, etc.

Extract the solutions and simplify

```
{{ysol, zsol}} = Simplify[{y[t], z[t]} /. sol,
                 Assumptions -> Element[u, Reals] && Element[zf, Reals] && t > 0 ]
```

Explore the solutions...

```
With[{y = ysol, z = zsol},
 Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{y, z}, {t, 0, tend}],
  {{tend, 0.759}, 0, 100},
  {{g, 0.354692}, 0, 10},
  {{zf, -1.8734}, -5, 10},
  {{u, 0.922386}, 0, 10}
 ]
]
```

You can use a numerical method to locate the conditions where the trajectory is within a given distance to a point, or use the WhenEvent option with NDSolve

---

In response to your comment,

I am not sure what you were trying to do, but here is an example of finding a (not necessarily unique) set of parameters that are close to the point (1,1).

```
FindMinimum[EuclideanDistance[{ysol, zsol}, {1, 1}], {g, u, zf, t}]
```

If you plug the result into the Manipulate (i.e., type them in by clicking the the "+" next to the slider), you will see that it finds a good approximation to a solution.

Comment: thank you, Craig. You have taken me a pretty suggestion and `Manipulate` is a very useful tool to have an idea about what is happening. But I'm a novice in mathematica...What do you have in mind when you talk about "numerical method etc..."?: in fact my greatest difficult is how to extract a list from the loop, and plot it...

Comment: @Mike84, I wasn't sure what you were looking for, but here is an example of how to find a trajectory that approaches a neighborhood of (1,1):

Comment: To begin I'm looking for the **first** `u` such that, given the other parameters, trajectory passes as close as possible to `zf` (say, an arbitrary small distance `e`). This problem may be solved with your methods. But for second step, I wish to find a graph `{t*,u*}` that compare the time `t*` taken to reach (a neighborhood of) `zf` given `u*`...It's for such problem that I tried with a do-loop (or similar)...Thank you very much!